# Citations broken after clearing auxiliary files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am writing a thesis and I had all of the citations working correctly. However, as I was half way through a new chapter some of the new citations that I was adding showed up as missing citations e.g. '[1-3,??]', even though the corresponding bibtex entries were there. In the past, when something like this has happened, I have found that deleting the auxiliary files and recompiling usually fixes this (or sometimes just opening the .bib file works, as if it tells TeXStudio to update the .bib file). However, this time, after deleting the auxiliary files and recompiling, instead of fixing the missing citations, now ALL of the citations in the entire thesis (not just this chapter) are broken. Any idea what might cause this behavior? And, any suggestions to fix it?

I am using TeXStudio on a Windows PC, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: you need to run bibtex to generate the bibliography

Comment: In the past, TeXStudio has always handled this automatically (i.e. citations work fine and the bibliography is generated, I never had to call bibtex separately, so I am assuming TeXStudio is running pdflatex and bibtex when I call 'Build&View'). Sometimes I have had to compile twice before everything works, but no matter how many times I compile now, the citations remain broken. Why would it suddenly stop working after clearing the auxiliary files (specifically, files with the following extensions were deleted: log,aux,dvi,lof,lot,bit,idx,glo,bbl,ilg,toc,ind,out,blg)?

Comment: I have no idea about texstudio but you have deleted the generated bibliography (bbl) so you need to run in order latex, bibtex, latex, latex, on your document to regenerate it.

Comment: Hmmm. You are right, searching through the log reveals that it was missing the .bbl file, and running latex, bibtex, latex, latex manually seems to have done the job. I wonder why TexStudio sometimes runs bibtex and other times doesn't. In any case, if you make your comment an answer I can accept it as solving this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea about texstudio but you have deleted the generated bibliography (`bbl`) so you need to run in order `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`, on your document to regenerate it.